# Не могу поднять локально страницу на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend

При запуске страницы вижу ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сам фронт, вообще не понимаю как это решить
Как это исправить?
Запускаю через live server

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том что у Вас не хватает драйвера для базы данных. 
С Live Server не работал, но на Debian подобных системах это решается установкой дополнительных модулей для PHP: 
`sudo apt-get install php8.2-pdo php8.2-pdo-mysql php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqllite`